# How do I change the intensity of f-curves (sound bakes to f-curves)

Tags: audio, fcurves

I'm making an audio visualizer with Blender, but my visualizer is all over the place and way to intense. I added the Envelope modifier, but it is still too intense. How can I make the f curves softer and overall have a lower intensity?

Comment: Scale at Y axis ... ?

Comment: I am really new to blender. This is going to sound stupid. How do I scale f-curves?

Comment: With mouse cursor in curve editor press S, Y and move cursor or type a value.